# PHP: Get hostname of external website by URL (determine if the hostname includes 'www')

Tags: php, web, hostname

Given I have an URL to an external website like `https://www.test.com' or 'https://test.com', but I'm not sure if the hostname of the external website actually includes 'www' or not. How can I determine this using PHP?

Comment: Of the 50 or so ways, have you tried any?

Comment: I googled for 30mins and so far I did not find any way to do it. Everyone seems to assume to know the correct URL.

Comment: Do you want to actually call the URL to see if it is valid or do you just want to know if a string contains 'www'?

Comment: @TheGentleman I need to call the URL, otherwise I wouldn't be able to know real hostname. That's where I'm struggling.

Answer (score 1):

You want to call the URL and check the status headers. Curl does this pretty well. Something like this should work.

```
$url = "https://test.com";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY,  true);
curl_setopt($ch, FOLLOW_LOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_exec($ch);

$returnCode = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); //200 = success, 4xx/5xx = error
if ($returnCode === 200) { //The url resolved and loaded
   //Do Stuff Here
} else if($returnCode === 301) { //The url resolved but forwarded to a different url        
    $effectiveURL = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); //The effective URL will be the final url in the chain (e.g. if www.test.com forwarded to test.com)
}
curl_close($ch);
```

That snippet will check if a URL exists and can be resolved successfully. It will also account for cases where the domain forwarded to another domain. You'll definitely need to wrap this in some more checking/logic (look into `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`) but this should get you started with the concept. You'll also probably want to adjust your timeout values to fit the specifics of your use case.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure why, but it doesn't work with this website: `https://www.planet-meat.de`. All others I tried so far worked.

Comment: That is b/c there is a redirect. Edited my answer to fix it.

Comment: Hm that is weird, I am testing this on my local machine and I dont get a 301, but a 403 for the mentioned url, all others work.

Comment: weird, I definitely get a 301 when I curl it manually from my console.